# What is ListItemCollectionPosition in SharePoint when doing pagination

Tags: 2016, visual-web-part, paging, splistitemcollection

I am developing a visual web part in SharePoint 2016 which is reading data from a list and displaying in ascending order using column `Name`.

I have read many tutorials especially the following but still unable to understand what exactly is this `ListItemCollectionPosition`.

[Learning SharePoint Part VII – List Pagination](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/colbyafrica/2009/02/19/learning-sharepoint-part-vii-list-pagination/)

[SharePoint List Pagination using SPListItemCollectionPosition](http://sharepoint.infoyen.com/2012/03/06/sharepoint-list-pagination-using-splistitemcollectionposition/)

These articles are very poorly written and just throw a lot of code and assume a lot of things. Here's my code so far and I am passing `pageinfo` as query string just to understand how this thing works. It seems I am either not passing correct parameter or my code is wrong. Right now my code is only displaying first 30 records from the list no matter what `pageinfo` I pass (Please see below examples that I am passing).

Here's my code:

**Code**

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url)) 
{   
   using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)     
   {        
      SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];        
      SPQuery query = new SPQuery();    
      query.RowLimit = 30; 
      SPListItemCollectionPosition position = new  SPListItemCollectionPosition(Page.Request.QueryString["pageinfo"]);       
      query.ListItemCollectionPosition = position;      
      SPListItemCollection itemCollection = list.GetItems(query);       
      foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)       
      {             
         //display data         
      }     
   } 
}
```

The values `pageinfo` for I am passing, I have taken these from the actual list itself i.e. if I do sort by `Name` column and then press Next button then this is how values are changing in browser URL. So I am using the same:

**To display first page**

`MyPage.aspx?pageinfo=SortField%3DName-SortDir%3DAsc`

**To display second page**

`MyPage.aspx?pageinfo=Paged%3DTRUE-p_Name%3DJohn%2520Anderson%2520Michael-p_ID%3D100-SortField%3DName-SortDir%3DAsc-PageFirstRow%3D31`

Comment: Have you checked this [ListItemCollectionPosition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee537050(v%3Doffice.15)?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

Comment: This shows all items. I want to only display for e.g. 10 items on each page with next and previous buttons.